PureScript: how to make build system produce multiple js outputs?
This would seem like a basic question, but I found no information on it. Websites don't typically consist of a single page. E.g. StackOverflow has menu on the left with Home, Questions, Tags links, and clicking either will trigger a unique GET request. Similarly, in my Purescript project I'd need to produce 3 different JS files, like tags.js, home.js, etc.
Currently I am using Spago, and am not finding way to do that, at least not a straightforward one. Having dug through documentation and spago options, the closest I managed to find are monorepos and polyrepos. But both are too cumbersome for such a simple usecase. At the very least they'd require you to produce a spago.yaml/dhall file and src directory for each page. But you'd typically have dozens of pages on a website! It can't be the way you're supposed to develop a frontend in PureScript, can it?
Neither I seem to see anything suitable in the output dir.
So, how do you produce unique javascript files for different pages? Preferrably with Spago, but it's not a requirement.

I think it's a overly broad question and it would probably help narrow down on what you're asking. Right now it's a mix between how to structure a purescript/js single page application and how to use spago to compile to multiple files. I didn't downvote.

@ChrisStryczynski thank you, can you please elaborate which part makes it sound as broad to you/what can I change? I am re-reading it, but from my POV it is clearly asking about the build process of producing multiple outputs. I can add a sentence "it's not about code structure", Idk if it'd make it any better. Though worth noting that any build tool would imply certain structure. E.g. if you look at my answer, you'll see that spago solution wouldn't work if you put multiple pages to a single file.

"so when a user clicks Tags, the backend would pick up tags.js and combine with HTML, likewise for other links". You also mention "pages". Spago should be agnonstic to html, clicks or links. This is more a question about SPA architecture I would say.

The sentence you quoted is a "usecase", it supposed to be a short introductory that explains to reader the background of the question. Spago indeed is agnostic to clicks and links, but Spago may (or may not) produce multiple outputs, and the outputs is what the question is about. With that said, do you think it's confusing to have this introduction at the beginning of the question? Or do you think this explanation should not be in the question at all, and instead question should be just "how to produce multiple js outputs with spago or pulp or other build tool"?

It's too broad. I think you should look into how SPAs are structured (you're probably just missing some routing functionality) as that is the usual "js way" of making an frontend app as far as I'm aware.

@ChrisStryczynski please see updated question. I reworded it to mention build system specifically and reduced it as much as possible, hopefully that addressed you concern that someone may feel like it's about code structure. Regarding SPAs, I didn't really get it, SPAs are the complete opposite of what's I'm doing/asking as they're just one file. I am also hoping if I get anywhere with this PureScript project, I'd set up server-side rendering, so those "js files" will be "html files". IMO proper websites do not provide a user with huge chunk of js just to render every existing page.

Having spent 2 days banging my head, I devised a solution, but it's kinda awkward. Surprisingly, for such popular usecase PureScript has exactly zero tooling and documentation (well, before this answer, apparently ), despite targeting web-devel first.
Code first, explanations later:
Code
Given two Halogen-based PureScript pages:

src/Common.purs:
module Common where

import Prelude
import Effect (Effect)
import Halogen as H
import Halogen.HTML as HH
import Halogen.Aff as HA
import Halogen.VDom.Driver (runUI)

helloWorldHeading :: String -> Effect Unit
helloWorldHeading text = HA.runHalogenAff do
  body <- HA.awaitBody
  runUI component unit body
  where
    component = H.mkComponent { initialState: const 0, render, eval: H.mkEval H.defaultEval}
    render _ = HH.h1 [ ] [ HH.text text ]


src/pages/Page1.purs:
module Page1 where

import Prelude
import Common (helloWorldHeading)
import Effect (Effect)

-- The `main` function. It needs to have name matching the one in build_pages.sh
-- script, and it should be unique enough so in the output js it's not renamed.
_pageMain :: Effect Unit
_pageMain = helloWorldHeading "Page1"


src/pages/Page2.purs:
module Page2 where

import Prelude
import Common (helloWorldHeading)
import Effect (Effect)

-- The `main` function. It needs to have name matching the one in build_pages.sh
-- script, and it should be unique enough so in the output js it's not renamed.
_pageMain :: Effect Unit
_pageMain = helloWorldHeading "Page2"



You produce unique output via build_pages.sh with the following content:
#!/bin/bash -eu

mkdir -p output/pages/
spago build # build here to skip that step later
for page in src/pages/*.purs; do
    filename=$(basename ${page})
    filename_noext="${filename%.*}"
    modname="${filename_noext^}" # same as capitalized filename w/o extension
    output_file="output/pages/${filename_noext}".js
    spago bundle-module --main "${modname}" --to ${output_file} --no-build
    # Remove the export. It spans multiple lines, but thankfully there is nothing
    # afterwards, so we just remove all lines starting with `^export`
    sed -i '/^export /,$d' ${output_file}
    # I'm not exactly sure why, but browser will be throwing errors unless the code
    # is wrapped into a lambda call. So do that.
    sed -i '1i (() => {
            $a _pageMain();})();' ${output_file}
done
spago bundle-app --no-build

Testing

Create HTML files at the top-level dir:

page1.html:
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Halogen App</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="output/pages/Page1.js"></script>
</body></html>


page2.html:
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Halogen App</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="output/pages/Page2.js"></script>
</body></html>




Run python -m http.server

Visit http://localhost:8000/page1.html and http://localhost:8000/page2.html in a browser.


You should see large text Page1 and Page2 accordingly.
Explanation
Fyodor Soikin hinted that it may be possible with spago bundle-module (not to be confused with bundle-app), but bundle-module alone does very little and is bad at it. Problems (being solved in the code section) are:

The command to produce a JS file from a Page1.purs is: spago bundle-module --main Modname --to output/Page1.js. That's it. A separate command for every page. Imagine having like a dozen of pages, you can't be running this command manually each time. So you need a script.
But then, a script won't get you far either, because even for "hello world" Halogen pages on a tmpfs the command takes about a second. So, like, for 5 pages you get to wait ≈4s for each rebuild, that's a lot. So now you have to wrap the build system to a build system that would track file changes and avoid running bundle-module for files that are unchanged.
I almost wrote a build.ninja generator for the usecase, but at some point dropped the ball because I already spent too much time on a seemingly simple task. I promise to update this answer with such generator if I get to use PureScript in production, but for now I decided to settle with just a script, similar to the one posted here.

Every such module needs an entry point and you can use main function everywhere. But apparently such name has high chance to clash with something, because in the JS output the entry point was getting named main2 for me, and I presume it may just as easily become main3 or main4. For this reason, I named it _pageMain, this way it's unlikely to get renamed.

The code spago bundle-module produces wouldn't work in a browser as is. You either need to modify it, or alternatively, you can make a "proxy file" import { _pageMain } from './Page1.js'; _pageMain(); and use this HTML syntax to make browser load it: <script type="module" src="output/pages/page1_proxy.js"></script>.
Now, from the development POV, maintaining such separate files, even if autogenerated, increases margin for mistakes and may potentially take additional time for going through them during debugging. So I'd advice against, make less code not more  In my solution I use a sed script that modifies the output file so that it becomes loadable.



Wanted to edit revision explanation, but there's a bug in SO that it simply drops it if there was no page change, and it's past 5 minutes now. So commenting here: the "build + --no-build" combination improves time in testing with local code 1.7s → 1.3s.

spago bundle-module is what you're looking for.
There is really no single ready-to-serve recipe, because it heavily depends on your setup, your hosting, your backend tech stack, and so on, and so on.
But in the most general terms, you would make a top-level "entry point" module for every such "navigation link" or whatever, make those modules export an entry point function each, and create a separate bundle from each of them via spago bundle-module. Then, in your HTML files, you include the bundle and call the entry point function from it.
An important thing to keep in mind is that spago bundle-module is more of a convenience thing, to tide you over. For small apps, small number of bundles, this works fine. But as your application grows, you would probably be better off calling esbuild (or a different bundler of your choice) directly.

Thanks. I dug into it and I see that bundle-module can produce a separate file with e.g. spago bundle-module --main PageOne --to output/PageOne.js. But that implies I'd have to write some sort of script for each .purs file, so it would track changes and call according bundle-module commands. Basically, I'd need to write a build system over the build system, which is odd. Perhaps am I missing something here?

Also, it doesn't seem to be working. I just tried loading a .js file produced by spago bundle-module --main Page1 --to output/Page1.js, and browser refuses to render with the error in console Uncaught SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module. Looking at the source, indeed Page1.js has an export … directive at the end of the file. In contrast, executing a spago bundle-app and inspecting index.js which loads fine shows no such directive in it (not anywhere for that matter). PS code is the same for both files, barring the X in module <X> where.

So, anyway, I was about to give up and just make up for-cycle scripts with sed removing the export line… But then turned out, even if you remove export stuff, you'd get another error Uncaught TypeError: cannot declare global binding 'document': property must be configurable or both writable and enumerable. So basically, I don't think your idea with spago bundle-module has any chance to work, unless I am missing something. The generated code seems to be simply unrunnable.
